# Texture with nothing aroud

Tags: ios, opengl-es, textures

I'm drawing into a texture which is binded to a FrameBuffer. Then I use it on a rectangle, where it can be moved to see particular areas of the texture.

When i'm outside of the drawn texture I want to have only a color

I tried on `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S/GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_L`

```
GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT
```

`GL_REPEAT` => I get color around my texture but the repeated texture is too near

```
GL_CLAMP_TO_EGDE
```

But it's not the result I want.

Any idea to help me ?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no IOS developer, but the edge modes you listed (repeat, mirror and clamp) are all the graphics hardware I know about supports, so I'd guess the iPhone/iPad GPUs will be similar.

If you can, make the texture 1 pixel larger at each border (so eg. use a 126x126 bitmap and paste it into the middle of a transparent 128x128 texture) and use clamp as the edge mode. This will not result in a sharp edge, however, since bilinear interpolation will still take place.

Otherwise, you'll have to do the math yourself, meaning that if your viewing rectangle reaches the border of the texture, you'll have to adjust the coordinates of the rendered quad instead of only its texture coordinates, eg.

```
upperLeftQuad.U = viewRectangle.X / textureWidth;
if(upperLeftQuad.U < 0) {
  upperLeftQuad.X += -(upperLeftQuad.U * textureWidth);
  upperLeftQuad.U = 0;
}

upperRightQuad.U = (viewRectangle.X + viewRectangle.Width) / textureWidth
if(upperLeftQuad.U > 1) {
  upperLeftQuad.X -= (upperLeftQuad.U * textureWidth);
  upperLeftQuad.U = 1;
}
```

Comment: Just for info : I working with a 1024*1024 texture, (first size bigger than the screen of the iPod/iPhone (960*640) since the texture must hold a copy of the screen.

Comment: And GL_CLAMP is not available with OpenGL-ES

Comment: I used your first solution. I redraw the texture in a smaller texture with a 1px border